# Unexpected result with "group by"-query

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing pagination stuff. I have sales transaction, each of which has a unique transaction id.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) from sale_history group by transaction_id";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$rows = $row[0];
print $rows; 
exit;
```

Data in my table is like:

```
sale id    item         customer     transaction_id
 1          abc           aaa           1234
 2          def           aaa           1234
 3          abc           bbb           9876
 4          def           bbb           9876
```

Now this count should give me row count 2, but it is giving me 1.

Comment: It's most likely giving you 2 rows in the result set, but you only fetch one of them > `mysql_fetch_row($query)` is only executed once.

Comment: For above data, your query returns two rows, each with `2` in field value. If `print $rows` output `1`, your data is not like the sample above. Note that `$row[0]` is not the query rows count, but the field in first row returned by your query (the count for `1234` records)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to output Number of Rows, you should use

```
mysql_num_rows


$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) from sale_history group by transaction_id";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: Why not just use `SELECT count(distinct transaction_id) FROM sale_history` ?

Comment: Absolutely better, but he have to know this function firstly

Comment: Thanks it is working now. pagination through jquery is best approach or with php script?

Comment: You are welcome, sure with PHP that it have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for mysql_num_rows()

***mysql_* is a depreacted library on php though. Use PDO or mysqli_* instead.